# Convert amounts in string format with commas and trailing minus mark to numeric or float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-structures

I have a column with numeric values in a string format with thousand separator commas and the minus marks stated at the end of the string for minus values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John', 'Tom', 'Simon', 'Jose','Jose'],
                     'Amount':['1,000.00','1,000.00-', '100.00', '100.00-','1,000,000.00-'],
                     'ExpectedAmount':[1000.00,-1000.00, 100.00, -100.00,-1000000.00],
                    })
```

I want to convert the values in the "Amount" column to a float while preserving whether the value is a plus or minus.

I can remove the commas using "replace"

```
df1['Amount1'] = df1['Amount'].str.replace(',','')
```

But I'm unable to change the position of the minus mark from the end of the string to the beginning of the string so that I can change the format from string to float.
Can someone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap minus sign with
`df1.Amount.apply(lambda x: '-' + x[:-1] if x[-1] == '-' else x)`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Patryk Kowalski

`df1['Amount1'] = df1['Amount'].apply(lambda x: '-' + x[:-1] if x[-1] == '-' else x)`

`df1['Amount1'] = df1['Amount1'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorial solution:

```
df1['ExpectedAmount'] = (df1['Amount'].str.replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
                        *df1['Amount'].str.endswith('-').mul(-2).add(1))
```

Remove all non digit/dot and convert to float

Multiply by -1 if the initial string ends with `'-'`

output:

```
    Name         Amount  ExpectedAmount
0   John       1,000.00          1000.0
1    Tom      1,000.00-         -1000.0
2  Simon         100.00           100.0
3   Jose        100.00-          -100.0
4   Jose  1,000,000.00-      -1000000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for swap `-` from back to start of string, remove `,` and casting to numeric:

```
df1['Amount'] = (df1['Amount'].replace({r'(.*)(-)$': r'\2\1', ',':''}, regex=True)
                              .astype(float))
print (df1)
    Name     Amount  ExpectedAmount
0   John     1000.0          1000.0
1    Tom    -1000.0         -1000.0
2  Simon      100.0           100.0
3   Jose     -100.0          -100.0
4   Jose -1000000.0      -1000000.0
```